# fprintf issues in writing and then reading

Tags: matlab, printf, notepad++, fopen

I'm trying to export a 2D matrix containing nodes coordinates of an Anys mesh (*.node), in Matlab. In this regard, I'm simply using fopen and fprintf commands in Matlab. For example:

========================================

`fid = fopen('c:\new_nodes.node', 'wt');
fprintf(fid,'%3d %10.4e %10.4e %19.4e\n',new_nodes');   % new_nodes : my 2D matrix`

=======================================

The content of generated file is okay but I cannot read it in Ansys, and when I open this file (e.g., new_nodes.node) in Notepad++ and do "save as", it becomes readable!!! It would be great if you could help me to find out whats the problem the Matlab code and how can I solve this problem...
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Using `\r` instead of `\n` may help.

Comment: Could not load FE model!

Comment: rahnema1, unfortunately, it didn't work...

Comment: Try using only `'w'` instead of `'wt'`  in the `fopen` function

Comment: why does it say `%19.4e` for the last value? Does the field need to be 19 long or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an error in the line brakes.

Open the file as `w` instead of `wt`

When you add the `t` matlab adds a `\r` after your `\n`

[edit @ 17:22]

```
fid = fopen('new_nodes.node', 'wt');
fprintf(fid,'%3d %10.4e %10.4e %19.4e\n',[pi 2.1 exp(1) 2.5]);
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('new_nodes.node','r');
B = fread(fid,inf,'*uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

Now B contains 56 values that sum to 2664. What do you get?

If I save it ase `new_nodes2.node` using notepad++ I get exactly the same values for B.

Comment: ok. couldn't you compare the two files (working vs non-working) at a byte-for-byte level? `fread(fid,inf,'*uint8')`

Comment: Gelliant, thanks for your help... in fact, I had not used the third part: fclose(fid);

Comment: Haha, ok, glad I could help. Often Matlab must release the file before another program may access it.